# Using Entity Framework with existing database error: "Invalid column" despite data annotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with an existing database with no FK constraints and I am using .NET MVC4 template with WebApi. I am trying to create a model like this

```
namespace My.Models {

  [Table("Risk")]
  public class Risk {

    [Key]
    [Column("RiskId")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Severity { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Occurrence { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    [Column("CreatedBy")]
    public UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
  }
}
```

The UserProfile is the Account model from the template including UserId, Email and Password.

```
  [Table("UserProfile")]
  public class UserProfile {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
  }
```

When I try and run the following query -

```
var risks = (from h in db.Risks
                     //where x.SomeField == SomeValue
                     orderby h.CreatedDate descending
                     select h).Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

I get an error: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'UserProfile_UserId'.`

I thought my Column annotation had already flagged to EF what it should be looking for. It seems to keep appending "_UserId" to whatever I say the column name is.

Comment: if you look at the database you will find a column called UserProfile_UserId, which is used to link the UserProfile table to the Risk Table

Comment: There isn't and I wouldn't want to create another column since it is already a populated database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreatedBy` is a navigation property. You can't apply the `[Column]` attribute to navigation properties. In order to configure the name of the foreign key column in the database you must use Fluent API. With your model it is not possible with data annotations alone:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Risk>()
    .HasOptional(r => r.CreatedBy) // or HasRequired
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("CreatedBy")); // this is the FK column name
```

Alternatively you can introduce the foreign key as property into your model and then use annotations:

```
[Table("Risk")]
public class Risk {

    [Key]
    [Column("RiskId")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    //...

    [Column("CreatedBy")]
    public int? CreatedById { get; set; }  // or int if CreatedBy is required

    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    public UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```